# Norm of ring extension is the same as norm of extension of field of fractions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Definition**. Let $S,R$ be integral domains with $S \subseteq R$ and let $R$ be a free $S$-module which is finitely generated. Then define the norm of an element $x$ as the determinant of the multiplicative map $\mu_x: R \to R, y \mapsto xy$ for all $x \in R$.

If one now has the extension $Q(R)$ over $Q(S)$, is the norm of an $x \in R$ the same as $N_{Q(R)/Q(S)}(x)$? If so, why is that the case? This would be fairly easy to see, if the $S$-basis, say $\{r_1,...,r_n\}$ of $R$, is also a $Q(S)$ basis for $Q(R)$ but I don't know if that is the case and why it should be.

**Edit.** Lemma $1$. $Q(R) \cong R \otimes_S Q(S)$ as $Q(S)$-Modules. Furthermore $R \otimes_S Q(R) \cong S^n \otimes_S Q(S) \cong Q(S)^n$ as $Q(S)$-modules.

If $\{r_1 \otimes 1,..., r_n \otimes 1\}$ would be a Basis of the $Q(S)$-module $R \otimes_S Q(S)$ one would obtain, due to the first isomorphism of Lemma $1$, that $\{r_1,...,r_n\}$ would be a $Q(S)$-Basis for $Q(R)$, which is what I want to show. Those $\{r_1 \otimes 1,...,r_n \otimes 1\}$ should span $R \otimes_S Q(S)$ as a $Q(S)$-module. Since this is a vector space and $\{r_1 \otimes 1,...,r_n \otimes 1\}$ are $n=\text{dim} (R \otimes_S Q(S))$ many elements that span this vector space, they are linearly independent and thus a basis.

Comment: Your last sentence is indeed true. See here, e.g.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762763/for-integral-domains-r-and-s-if-s-simeq-rn-as-r-modules-does-mathr/3762797#3762797

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thanks for your comment. I have made an edit to my post, trying to show that the elements are indeed the required basis. Could you tell me if you spot mistakes in my argument?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you very much!